# Why can I publish individual web jobs but not a web project with a list of web jobs?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

We have a WebJobs-enabled project that we use to deploy and schedule WebJobs. A couple of our developers are able to publish the project but I am getting an error when attempting to do so. The publish itself succeeds but I get a bunch of errors at the very end saying:

`An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.`

I have tried to publish a WebJob on its own using the **Publish as a WebJob** command and it worked just fine. The publish profile that I am using validates just fine too. Why does it work for one but not for the other?

Answer (score 0):

My account with Co-administrator privileges on the subscription, I could publish my [WebJobs-enabled project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs) to Azure App Service successfully (both website and webjob run fine). [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009814/403-forbidden-publishing-azure-web-job-from-visual-studio) discussed a similar issue, and we could find that account without Co-administrator privileges may cause this issue, so please make sure whether your account has Co-administrator privileges.