# Getting 403 Forbidden while trying to run WebJob through Webhook

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to run a WebJob using Webhook with the username and password. In postman it works fine with the basic auth.

I took the code generated for Powershell from Postman and tried running from Powershell but it gives me 403 Forbidden error. Any idea why forbidden for Powershell?

Comment: Feel free to share your code.

Comment: $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic ENCRYPTED TOKEN")
$headers.Add("Cookie", "COOKIE")

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'URL' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers
$response | ConvertTo-Json

Answer (score 0):

- One possible cause of a 403 error is that the Storage account that the web job accesses is in a different subscription than the one where it is hosted.
- Try changing the subscription of storage account to the same of web job to see if it works.
- Other reasons for the 403 forbidden error could exist. For example, page cache and cookie logging in. To learn how to fix the 403 Forbidden Error, refer this [article](https://www.lifewire.com/403-forbidden-error-explained-2617989). 403 errors are usually often generated by trying to access something you don't have permission to access.
  **References**
  [Azure App Service Deploy returns (403) Forbidden with IP restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477361/azure-app-service-deploy-returns-403-forbidden-with-ip-restriction) ,
  [403 (Forbidden) publishing Azure Web Job from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009814/403-forbidden-publishing-azure-web-job-from-visual-studio)