# Azure WebJobs - Multiple Web Apps - Single Storage account conflict

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Use case:
We have one App service plan, with multiple azure web apps, hosting the same web applications. Each web application also has one web job. For the Webjob Dashboards, we use the same storage account for all web apps. 
Can there be any potential conflict between the webjobs? Like the Webjob dashboards show wrong information, or deployment of a webjob could be affected

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what are the webjobs are executing. Queue triggers? Timer triggers? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Edit,

I'm talking from environment / deployment point of view. First situation:
If I'm publish  3 different webjobs to an web app, can there be a conflict during deployment? 
Second situation, all 3 webjobs use the same storage account for AzureWebJobsDashboard and  AzureWebJobsStorage values in Application settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can there be any potential conflict between the webjobs?

It depends on your WebJobs functions logic, concurrent access can result in resource contention, which might cause conflicts. For example, if two jobs access and operate same resource at the same time, these jobs may affect each other, and conflicts would happen.

Please refer to the [Conflicts section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs#conflicts) to consider conflicts issue when you design the WebJobs.

Comment: Edit,

I'm talking from environment / deployment point of view. First situation:
If I'm publish  3 different webjobs to an web app, can there be a conflict during deployment? 
Second situation, all 3 webjobs use the same storage account for AzureWebJobsDashboard and  AzureWebJobsStorage values in Application settings

Comment: ``First situation: If I'm publish 3 different webjobs to an web app, can there be a conflict during deployment?`` Normally it enables us to publish multiple different WebJobs to an Azure web app. But [publish scheduled WebJob in free tier web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991519/error-creating-webjob-schedule) might fail with error.

Comment: ``Second situation, all 3 webjobs use the same storage account for AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage values in Application settings`` specify same storage account as connection string **AzureWebJobsDashboard** for all 3 WebJobs is ok. Besides, as I mentioned in my reply, different WebJobs access same Azure storage resource can result in resource contention, which might cause conflicts.